# Alamofire 5 Adapting and Retrying Requests

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire

I am trying to implement my OAuth2 flow using Alamofire 5.0.0-beta.3. As i can see the documentation is still for Alamofire 4 as stated in the github page as well.

I am trying to make the Oauth2 handler following the documentation for Alamofire 4. As the class names are changed, I am completely lost while making it.

**This is the code that i am following:**

```
class OAuth2Handler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {
    private typealias RefreshCompletion = (_ succeeded: Bool, _ accessToken: String?, _ refreshToken: String?) -> Void

    private let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    private let lock = NSLock()

    private var clientID: String
    private var baseURLString: String
    private var accessToken: String
    private var refreshToken: String

    private var isRefreshing = false
    private var requestsToRetry: [RequestRetryCompletion] = []

    // MARK: - Initialization

    public init(clientID: String, baseURLString: String, accessToken: String, refreshToken: String) {
        self.clientID = clientID
        self.baseURLString = baseURLString
        self.accessToken = accessToken
        self.refreshToken = refreshToken
    }

    // MARK: - RequestAdapter

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        if let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString, urlString.hasPrefix(baseURLString) {
            var urlRequest = urlRequest
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            return urlRequest
        }

        return urlRequest
    }

    // MARK: - RequestRetrier

    func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }

        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
            requestsToRetry.append(completion)

            if !isRefreshing {
                refreshTokens { [weak self] succeeded, accessToken, refreshToken in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                    strongSelf.lock.lock() ; defer { strongSelf.lock.unlock() }

                    if let accessToken = accessToken, let refreshToken = refreshToken {
                        strongSelf.accessToken = accessToken
                        strongSelf.refreshToken = refreshToken
                    }

                    strongSelf.requestsToRetry.forEach { $0(succeeded, 0.0) }
                    strongSelf.requestsToRetry.removeAll()
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private - Refresh Tokens

    private func refreshTokens(completion: @escaping RefreshCompletion) {
        guard !isRefreshing else { return }

        isRefreshing = true

        let urlString = "\(baseURLString)/oauth2/token"

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "access_token": accessToken,
            "refresh_token": refreshToken,
            "client_id": clientID,
            "grant_type": "refresh_token"
        ]

        sessionManager.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { [weak self] response in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                if 
                    let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], 
                    let accessToken = json["access_token"] as? String, 
                    let refreshToken = json["refresh_token"] as? String 
                {
                    completion(true, accessToken, refreshToken)
                } else {
                    completion(false, nil, nil)
                }

                strongSelf.isRefreshing = false
            }
    }
}
```

**This is how to use this for alamofire 4:**

```
let baseURLString = "https://some.domain-behind-oauth2.com"

let oauthHandler = OAuth2Handler(
    clientID: "12345678",
    baseURLString: baseURLString,
    accessToken: "abcd1234",
    refreshToken: "ef56789a"
)

let sessionManager = SessionManager()
sessionManager.adapter = oauthHandler
sessionManager.retrier = oauthHandler

let urlString = "\(baseURLString)/some/endpoint"

sessionManager.request(urlString).validate().responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

This is the link i am following to implement this. 
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests

Comment: were you able to make this work properly ? I tried the suggested solution using the RequestInterceptor class, but for some reason my requests get retried many times.

Answer (score 13):

Look at something like this.

```
 struct EnvironmentInterceptor: RequestInterceptor {

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest>) -> Void) {
        var adaptedRequest = urlRequest
        guard let token = AtraqService.shared.user?.token.accessToken else {
        completion(.success(adaptedRequest))
        return
        }
        adaptedRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        completion(.success(adaptedRequest))
     }

     func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
        //get token
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
        Session(configuration: configuration,  interceptor: EnvironmentInterceptor())
```

Finally

```
request().validate().response...
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works. But for some reason the request gets retried many times. Do you have an example? the Alamofire documentation example even calls some sort of self.lock() method.

Comment: why you have used 'struct' for EnvironmentInterceptor?

Comment: Do not use responseJSON or responseDATA, use just response. This link explains why retry called twice :). https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2562

Comment: @ahsan were you able to save list of requests to be retried?

Answer (score 1):

If Alamofire 5 is not intercepting (adapting or retrying) your requests for some reason, then just try to check the delegate signature out [as described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307960/5969121)

```
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (AFResult<URLRequest>) -> Void) {
    var modifiedURLRequest = urlRequest
    let apiToken = config.apiToken
    modifiedURLRequest.setValue(apiToken, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.apiTokenHeader)
    completion(.success(modifiedURLRequest))
}

func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
    completion(.doNotRetry)
}
```

Here's the difference (look at the signature):

```
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Alamofire.Session, completion: @escaping (AFResult<URLRequest>) -> Void) {
    var modifiedURLRequest = urlRequest
    let apiToken = config.apiToken
    modifiedURLRequest.setValue(apiToken, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.apiTokenHeader)
    completion(.success(modifiedURLRequest))
}

func retry(_ request: Alamofire.Request, for session: Alamofire.Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
    completion(.doNotRetry)
}
```